# Porque os caracteres [ ] são processados desta forma na minha URL?

Tags: html, url, get

Ao enviar um `$_GET` da minha aplicação tenho a seguinte expressão `tipo%5B%5D=CASA` na minha ***url***. Os dados são provenientes de um elemento HTML do tipo ***checkbox*** de `name="tipo[]"`.

Estes caracteres representam simplesmente `[` e `]`.

Alguém sabe porque isto está acontecendo e como resolver isto?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="APARTAMENTO/APTO DUPLEX" id="tp1">
<label for="tp1">Apartamento</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="CASA" id="tp2">
<label for="tp2">Casa</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="CASA EM CONDOMINIO" id="tp3">
<label for="tp3">Casa Condomínio</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem nada de errado nessa string. Isso é uma maneira de codificar caracteres para serem transmitidos seguramente (com um código que não permite enganos).

Assim:

> **%5B** é '['
>   **%5D** é ']'
>   **%20** é um espaço em branco

Se quiser ter isso de volta a uma string em javascript pode usar assim:

```
decodeURI('tipo%5B%5D=CASA')
// resultado: "tipo[]=CASA"
```

```js
var codificado = 'tipo%5B%5D=CASA';
var descodificado = decodeURI(codificado);
alert(descodificado);
```